# Why isn't this widget displaying one of the icons?

Tags: widgets

I have coded a widget. In the admin area the user can enter the url for their youtube, facebook, twitter and google+. On the front end of the site in the browser, they can click on a logo for either of these 4, & it will take them to the social network. Logos for facebook, twitter & youtube are dispaying, but the youtube one isn't.

Please can you have a look at my code (below) and tell me why the youtube logo isn't being displayed? :

```
 class mp_example_widget02 extends WP_widget {

    function mp_example_widget02() {
    parent::WP_widget(false, $name = ' Follow us');
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract( $args );

    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
    $address = $instance['address'];
    $email =  $instance['email'];
    $phone =  $instance['phone'];

    echo $before_widget;

    if ( $title ) {
    echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;  
    }

    if ( $address ) {
    echo  ' <div class="widget-textarea">' . $address . ' </div> '; 
    }

    if ( $email ) {
    echo '<a href="mailto:' .antispambot($email) .'"  > ' .$email . '</a><br />';
      }

    if ( $phone ) {
    if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    echo  "<a href='tel:$phone'  >$phone</a><br />";
    }else{
    echo '
         <div class="widget-textphone">' . $phone . ' </div> '; 
         }
         }


    echo $after_widget;
    }

     function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
     $instance = $old_instance;
     $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
     $instance['address'] = strip_tags($new_instance['address']);
     $instance['email'] = ( is_email($new_instance['email']) ) ? $new_instance['email'] : '';
    $instance['phone'] = strip_tags($new_instance['phone']);



     return $instance;
     }

     function form($instance) {

     $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
     $address = esc_attr($instance['address']);
     $email = esc_attr($instance['email']);
     $phone = esc_attr($instance['phone']);
     ?>

     <p>
     <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?> ">
     <?php _e('Title'); ?>  </label>
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?> " />
     </p>
 <p>

        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('address'); ?>"><?php _e('Address'); ?></label>

        <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('address'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('address'); ?>"><?php echo $address; ?></textarea>

    </p> 
    <br /> <br /> <p></p>

     <p>
    <label for="<?php echo  $this->get_field_id('email'); ?>">
     <?php _e('Email'); ?>  </label>
     <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('email'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('email'); ?>" type="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?> " />
    </p>


     <p> <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('phone'); ?> ">
     <?php _e('Phone'); ?> </label>
     <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('phone'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('phone'); ?>" type="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" />

        </p>

    <?php
    }
    }

    add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("mp_example_widget");'));


class phone_social02 extends WP_Widget {

    function phone_social02() {
        parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = __('Share us', 'phone_social02') );
    }

function form($instance) {
if( $instance) {

     $email = esc_attr($instance['email']);
     $youtube = esc_attr($instance['youtube']);
     $facebook = esc_attr($instance['facebook']);
     $twitter = esc_attr($instance['twitter']);
     $gplus = esc_attr($instance['gplus']);
     } else {
     $title = '';
     $telephone = '';
     $email = '';
     $youtube = '';
     $facebook = '';
     $twitter = '';
     $gplus = '';
    }
?>

<p>
</p>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('youtube'); ?>"><?php _e('Youtube:', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('youtube'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('youtube'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php if(empty($youtube)) { echo "http://";} else { echo $youtube; } ?>" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('facebook'); ?>"><?php _e('Facebook URL:', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('facebook'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('facebook'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php if(empty($facebook)) { echo "http://";} else { echo $facebook; } ?>" />
</p>

<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('twitter'); ?>"><?php _e('Twitter URL:', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('twitter'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('twitter'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php if(empty($twitter)) { echo "http://";} else { echo $twitter; } ?>" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('gplus'); ?>"><?php _e('Google Plus URL:', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('gplus'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('gplus'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php if(empty($gplus)) { echo "http://";} else { echo $gplus; } ?>" />
</p>
<?php }



function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
      $instance = $old_instance;

      $instance['email'] = strip_tags($new_instance['email']);
      $instance['youtube'] = strip_tags($new_instance['youtube']);
      $instance['facebook'] = strip_tags($new_instance['facebook']);
      $instance['twitter'] = strip_tags($new_instance['twitter']);
      $instance['gplus'] = strip_tags($new_instance['gplus']);

           return $instance;
}


function widget($args, $instance) {
   extract( $args );


   $email = $instance['email'];
   $facebook = $instance['youtube'];
   $facebook = $instance['facebook'];
   $twitter = $instance['twitter'];
   $gplus = $instance['gplus'];

   echo $before_widget;


      echo '<div id="phonesocialmain">';
      echo '<div id="socialdetmain">';


   echo'<p>Follow us: </p>';
   if( $youtube ) {
     echo '<a href="'.$youtube.'" target="_blank"> <img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/you3.png" height="35" width="35" alt="youtube"></a>';
    }
    if ( $facebook ) {
   echo  '<a href="'.$facebook.'" target="_blank"><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/fb3.png" height="35" width="35" alt="facebook"></a>';  
   }
   if ( $twitter ) {
   echo  '<a href="'.$twitter.'" target="_blank"><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri ().'/images/twit3.png" height="35" width="35" alt="Twitter"></a>';  
   }
   if ( $gplus ) {
 echo  '<a href="'.$gplus.'" target="_blank"><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/go3.png" height="35" width="35" alt="gplus"></a>';  
   }
   echo  '</div>'; 

  echo '</div>'; 
    echo '</div>';
   echo $after_widget;
}
}   

add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("phone_social02");'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `$facebook = $instance['youtube'];` instead of `$youtube = $instance['youtube'];`

Comment: Thank-you for that. I have corrected that but it still doesn't seem to be displaying.

Comment: Then you're going to need to debug line by line, if you `print_r($instance)` is youtube in there?  Does the image linked actually exist where it's supposed to?

Comment: are you positive that `images/you3.png` exists?

Comment: @karpstrucking yes it does, I've checked this. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewBartel if I use `print_r($instance);` just before the last `echo $after_widget;` then youtube isn't in there. Thank-you for the support!

Comment: @AndrewBartel I've discovered something quite odd, if I put a url in widget area for youtube it shows the youtube logo. If no url has been entered then the youtube logo doesn't display. For facebook, twitter and google+ the logos display even if no urls have been entered into the widget area.